# evaluate the integral by writing it as a sum of two integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

evaluate the integral by writing it as a sum of two integrals

$$\int\frac{4x+9}{x^2+6x+13}\,\mathrm dx$$

my answer is that

$2\ln(x^2+6x+13)-3/2\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$

that correct ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice
\begin{align}
\int\frac{4x+9}{x^2+6x+13}\,dx&=\int\frac{4x+12}{(x+3)^2+2^2}\,dx-\int\frac{3}{(x+3)^2+2^2}\,dx\\
&=\int\frac{2(2x+6)}{(x+3)^2+2^2}\,dx-\int\frac{3}{(x+3)^2+2^2}\,dx\\
&=\color{red}{2\ln(x^2+6x+13)-\frac{3}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)+C}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{4x+9}{x^2+6x+13}dx = \int\frac{\left[(4x+12)-3\right]}{x^2+6x+13}dx$

So Integral $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{4x+12}{x^2+6x+13}dx-3\int\frac{1}{x^2+6x+13}dx$

$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{4x+12}{x^2+6x+13}dx-3\int\frac{1}{(x+3)^2+2^2}dx$

So $\displaystyle  I = 2\ln\left|x^2+6x+13\right|-3\cdot \frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)+\mathcal{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int \frac{4x+9}{x^2+6x+13}dx$$
$$=\int \frac{2(2x+6)-3}{x^2+6x+13}dx$$

$$=2\int \frac{2x+6}{x^2+6x+13}dx-3\int \frac{1}{x^2+6x+13}dx$$
$$=2\color{red}{I_1}-3\color{blue}{I_2}$$
$$\implies I_1=\int \frac{2x+6}{x^2+6x+13}dx$$
Let, $x^2+6x+13=t\iff (2x+6)dx=dt$

$$\color{red}{I_1}=\int \frac{1}{t}dt=\ln|t|$$$$=\color{red}{\ln\left|x^2+6x+13\right|}$$

$$\implies \color{blue}{I_2}=\int \frac{1}{x^2+6x+13}dx=\int \frac{1}{(x+3)^2+2^2}dx$$
Let $x+3=2\tan \theta\iff dx=2\sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$=\int \frac{2\sec^2\theta }{(2\tan \theta)^2+4}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sec^2\theta }{\tan^2\theta+1}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\theta=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)}$$

Hence, we get 
$$\int \frac{4x+9}{x^2+6x+13}dx=2\color{red}{I_1}-3\color{blue}{I_2}$$$$=2\ln\left|x^2+6x+13\right|-\frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)+C$$

Your answer is not correct.